# a function to partition images into patches

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a function that partitions an image into multiple patches. Here is the function, are there any suggestions to make it better or more production ready in terms of the best software practice?

```
def cal_patches(img,num_colums):
   patch_list = [] 
   num_rows = num_colums
   x,y,w,h = 0,0, int(img.shape[1]/num_colums), int(img.shape[0]/ num_rows)
   ind = 0
   for i in range(num_colums):
     x= 0
     for j in range(num_rows):  
       ind += 1
       y_end = min(y+h, img.shape[0])
       x_end = min(x+w, img.shape[1])
       patch = img[y: y_end, x: x_end]
       patch_list.append(patch)
       x += w
     y += h
   return patch_list
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Is there any other surrounding code you can show us - particularly what `img` is, and how it's loaded?

Comment: My bets are on [tag:numpy] being involved here.

Comment: What is the point of this code? What makes it useful?

Comment: I dont think "what makes this code useful" is a *useful* remark here. I would very much appreciate verification of `img` being a numpy array though, that's extremely relevant to possible solutions that avoid double looping.

Comment: Apart from the nice feedback you got already, perhaps check out numpy's [array_split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) method. Not so much to their code or how it's inmpemented there, but just so you can use that method for this use case and don't need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### PEP-8 Guidelines

Your code violates the PEP-8 standard in several area, including (but not limited to):

- Operators should have 1 space before and after the operator (`y + h` instead of `y+h`)
- One space after commas (`x, y, w, h` not `x,y,w,h`)
- Slices should not have any spaces around the colon (`y:y_end` not `y: y_end`)

### Spelling

Columns is spelt with an `n`.

### Meaningful names

I don't know what `cal_patches` means.  Is `cal` short for "calculate"?  Your question title says "partition"; perhaps that should be part of the function name.

### `docstring`

Add a doc-string to `help()` the user understand what the function does, and what the function returns ... without having to consult the source code.

### Type Hints

With Python 3.6+, you can add type hints to the function to further improve understanding about what the function requires and what it returns:

```
def cal_patches(img: Image, num_colums: int) -> List[Image]:
```

### Useful arguments

The function can partition the image into a number of vertical columns.  What if I wanted a number of rows as well?  I can't request that.

Oh wait!  It does do rows too.  But always the same number of rows and columns.  Perhaps add `num_rows` to the argument list too?

### Integer division

`int(n / d)` is verbose and unnecessary.  Use the integer division operator `n // d`.

### Unused variables

`ind` is never used anywhere, and could be removed.

`i` and `j` are never used anywhere, so could be replaced by the "throwaway" variable `_`.  Even better, you could use the `w` and `h` values as the step size for the `range()`, and get rid of the `x += w` and `y += h` statements:

### Avoid calculating unchanging values

In the inner loop, `y` is not changing, so `y_end` results in the same value each iteration of the inner loop.  It can be moved out of the inner loop.

### Bug?

The inner loop goes over the number rows, but is increase `x` by `w`, which is a column increment.  Did you accidentally swap the rows and columns?  It works as long as `num_rows == num_columns`, but it will cause grief when that is relaxed.

---

### Updated code

```
def create_image_patches(img, num_rows, num_columns):
    """
    Partition an image into multiple patches of approximately equal size.
    The patch size is based on the desired number of rows and columns.
    Returns a list of image patches, in row-major order.
    """

    patch_list = []
    width, height = img.shape[1], img.shape[0]
    w, h = width // num_columns, height // num_rows

    for y in range(0, height, h): 
        y_end = min(y + h, width)
        for x in range(0, width, w):
            x_end = min(x + w, height)
            patch = img[y:y_end, x:x_end]
            patch_list.append(patch)

    return patch_list
```

Add type hints using the `typing` module.

---

### Generator

As suggested by [@Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98493/graipher), this function could be turned into a generator, which may be useful depending on how the patches are processed downstream:

```
def generate_image_patches(img, num_rows, num_columns):
    """
    Generate image patches of approximately equal size from a source image.
    The patch size is based on the desired number of rows and columns.
    Patches are generated in row-major order.
    """

    width, height = img.shape[1], img.shape[0]
    w, h = width // num_columns, height // num_rows

    for y in range(0, height, h): 
        y_end = min(y + h, width)
        for x in range(0, width, w):
            x_end = min(x + w, height)
            yield img[y:y_end, x:x_end]
```

A "helper" function could be used to turn the generator back into a `list`, if required for existing callers of the function:

```
def create_image_patches(img, num_rows, num_columns):
    """
    Partition an image into multiple patches of approximately equal size.
    The patch size is based on the desired number of rows and columns.
    Returns a list of image patches, in row-major order.
    """

    return list(generate_image_patches(img, num_rows, num_columns))
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize `x` and `y` to zero, the `for` loop will already do that. I would also consider making this a generator, depending on how the resulting patches are processed.

Comment: @Graipher Re: x & y, good point!  I reviewed pretty much from top down, and applied my comments to create the “Updated code” ... I clearly needed to do a two-pass review to catch the new redundancies.  Re: generator.  Fair point.  I hesitate to introduce too many new concepts into one review, but there is no “beginner” tag, so unless someone beats me to it, I’ll update my answer to include generation ... in a little while when I have time.